# swift code error page 21

Tags: swift, function

Hi all I am learning Swift, just going through the book provided by Apple on the app store. On page 21 there is some code and for the life of me I cannot get it to work. Just wondered if anybody could shed light. I am pretty sure it's an update thing but if someone could point me or help that would be great. Here is the code taken from the book (yes I have re-typed exactly)

```
func hasAnyMatches(list: [Int], condition: (Int) -> Bool) -> Bool {
    for item in list {
        if condition(item) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
func lessThanTen(number: Int) -> Bool {
    return number < 10
}
var numbers = [20, 19, 7, 12]

hasAnyMatches(numbers, condition: lessThanTen)
```

However when I put the code in it changes it and shows the condition arg in the function call as shown below. I should point out that I have placed a question mark after condition: as I am not sure what data type Int -> Bool is asking for.

[image: I have placed a question mark after condition as I am not entirely sure what Int -> Bool is asking for.]

Comment: Mike, you need to type in a number after the word condition, then it will tell you if your number is smaller than the numbers in its list?

Comment: Note also that for questions here on SO, you should post code in code blocks (see my edit) rather than post images of code.

Comment: What version of XCode are you using? On my side with XCode 7.2.1 this works.

Comment: This now fully works. I do not know why the original code didn't work. I  believe I was deleting the condition and place the lessThanTen. I realise should have posted own code, sorry about that. Latest XCode. I normally develop in Objective-C but it's the holidays so I thought I'd learn Swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `Int -> Bool` is a *function type* that takes a single argument of type `Int`, and returns a value of type `Bool`. In this sense, `hasAnyMatches` is a higher order function, in that it expects, in addition to an integer array, a function as an argument. Hence, you can send e.g. a function reference (to an `(Int) -> Bool` function) or a closure as the second argument to `hasAnyMatches)`.

An example follows below, calling `hasAnyMatches` with 1. a function reference; 2. an anonymous closure; 3. a pre-defined closure:

```
func hasAnyMatches(list: [Int], condition: (Int) -> Bool) -> Bool {
    for item in list {
        if condition(item) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
func lessThanTen(number: Int) -> Bool {
    return number < 10
}
var numbers = [20, 19, 7, 12]    

/* 1. function reference: to 'lessThanTen' function */
hasAnyMatches(numbers, condition: lessThanTen)

/* 2. anonymous (trailing) closure: (Int) -> Bool: "integer less than 0?" */
hasAnyMatches(numbers) { myInteger in myInteger < 0 }
hasAnyMatches(numbers) { $0 < 0 } /* short form */

/* 3. pre-defined closure: (Int) -> Bool: "integer larger than 0?" */
let myIntToBoolClosure : (Int) -> Bool = {
    myInteger in
    return myInteger > 0
}
hasAnyMatches(numbers, condition: myIntToBoolClosure)
```

Comment: Thanks @dfri I am just getting to grips with closures within Swift. I like Swift I am very impressed with it. This is a great answer.

Comment: @Mike Happy to help, and welcome to Swift! I agree it's a very neat language; among many things the functional programming aspects of it. For future reference, in the context of asking questions here on StackOverflow: note that you can include code blocks (such as the above) when posting questions, rather than a image of your code. You simply paste your code into your question; selects the code and thereafter press the little `{}` code block button available in the top of the question editor. Good luck on your Swift journey!